# Regex - Match any sequence which repeats itself n times

Tags: regex

Do you know how to match a group which repeats itself n times? e.g.:

> This **is is is is** a test       `[incl. the spaces between two 'is']`
>   F**oo** bar
>   T**elel**ephone: +49 1**88**/123 **45 45 45**

I tried the following regex pattern: `(\w+)\1+`
but it only matches *two* occurences of a group (and not *n* occurences)

Thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your pattern with respect to your sample input is that the pattern does not account for possible trailing spaces:

```
(\w+\s*)\1+
```

[Demo.](https://regex101.com/r/vL6oE2/1)

This is not universal, though: for example, this pattern will match "a ba ba ba ba b" as "a **ba ba ba ba** b", not as "**a ba ba ba ba b**".

Comment: It will fail for `fooooo bar`.. `\w+` must be greedy.. `\w+?`

Comment: I changed it to `(\s*\w+?\s*)\1+` to also match leading spaces.
Thank you very much for your quick answer :)